# R: GA package Discrete input parameters

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, mixed-integer-programming

**What changes are to be made so that the input parameters are considered to be discrete/integer values?**

Making high penalties in the fitness function is not the right option as it becomes a part of the iterative process.
skipping the non-integer values is again a part of iterative process.
Something needs to be changed in:

`ga(type = c("binary", "real-valued", "permutation"), min, max, nBits, fitness, ..., )`

to make the function take in only integer/ discrete parameters.
I have four discrete params.

Same problem would come up with `MINLP` problems.

I cant figure it out :(
Thanks..

Comment: Could you encode your possible integer levels as one hot values? E.g., if A could be 1,2,3 you would make decisions A1, A2, A3 with possible values of 0 or 1 depending on whether each was chosen. An alternative is to round the real-valued decision when calculating the objective function. Unfortunately either way is computationally inefficient.